# Encontrar el primer número que sea > 0 en listas

Tags: r, bucle-for, rstudio, r-dplyr

realice la siguiente simulación con una función programada en el cual se tenían que hacer 1000 simulaciones:

```
CLExp <- function(u,Ti, c, lambda, alpha){
  # Tiempo al tiempo t
  t = 0
  Ct = u 
  vt = 0  
  vCt = u
  while(t < Ti) {
    Tn = rexp(1,lambda)
    t = t + Tn
    vt = c(vt,t)
    Yn = rexp(1, alpha) 
    Ct = Ct + c*Tn-Yn
    vCt = c(vCt, Ct)
  }
  return(list(tiempo = vt, capital = vCt))
}

# Número de simulaciones: 
nsim <- 1000

# Simulación aplicando sapply: 
Resultados <- sapply(1:nsim, 
                     function(x) {
                       CLExp(u, Ti, c, lambda, alpha)
                     })
```

El problema es que tengo que registar el número que por primera vez es menor o igual a cero, hice el siguiente intento pero me registra todos aquellos menores a cero y yo solo deseo conocer la posición y el primero que sea menor a cero:

```
results <- numeric()
# Ciclo for para encontrar el capital en el tiempo t que es menor o igual a cero: 
for (i in 1:nsim) {
    
    for (j in 1:length(Resultados[[2,i]])) {
      
      if (Resultados[[2,i]][j]<= 0) {
        
        results[j] <- as.data.frame(Resultados[[2,i]][j])
        
        }
    }
}

class(results)
# Convirtiendo el objeto lista en un data frame: 
df <- ldply (results, data.frame)
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

> #Obtenemos valores TRUE o FALSE si cumplimos la condición deseada:
>
> ```
> Resultados[[2,i]][j]<= 0
> ```
>
> #Realizamos la suma cumulativa:
>
> ```
> cumsum(Resultados[[2,i]][j]<= 0)
> ```
>
> #Indentificamos los índices para los que la suma cumulativa es igual a 1:
>
> ```
> which(cumsum(Resultados[[2,i]][j]<= 0) == 1)
> ```
>
> #Finalmente, como queremos encontrar el primer índice donde se cumple la condición, seleccionamos el menor de los índices:
>
> ```
> min(which(cumsum(Resultados[[2,i]][j]<= 0) == 1))
> ```